# Voice over: Read items of table cell separately - not as a whole

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, voiceover

Voice over reads the whole cell (all the items without pauses and a need to select next element), then after each right swipe it reads each of the items again one by one. I can get read of the second but not the first. I need to remove the focus from the cell as a whole, and have Voice Over announce its labels one by one, as if it wasn't a table cell at all.
I tried playing with `accessibilityElementsHidden`, `shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren` and `isAccessibilityElement`, but I only managed to remove Voice Over for the cell completely or remove separate items reading, leaving reading it as a whole, which is the opposite of what I need. How do I remove the focus from the ell as a whole leaving focuses for all of its items separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make every separate item accessible, with sensible accessibility label, only then VoiceOver stops announcing the whole cell.

Comment: How to do that? Can you give an example?